# Java Collection - Top and Bottom n elements

Tags: java, sorting, collections, filtering

I have a rather unique requirement where in my collection should hold only the Top and Bottom n elements. The elements are comparable and the Collection itself is bounded which means the evaluation is done at the time of adding an entry to the Collection.

For example when the following set of values are inserted in to a "Top and Bottom 10" Collection

5, 15, 10, 1, 12, 8, 11, 2, 16, 14, 9, 3, 20, 7

the Collection should hold only the following

20, 16, 15, 14, 12, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1

I was thinking of maintaining 2 SortedSet of n/2 elements and then merging them in the end however the approach isnt clean and requires the merge step before consuming the results.

Just hoping someone would have a better answer to this problem.

Comment: You probably only need one Treeset - the subset method can give you easy access to top / bottom 5 only and the lower/higher methods to test inclusion. + pollFirst/Last to remove the right item. But you still need to code it.

Comment: I did go through the TreeSet API (subset and tailset) but since most operations are based on the element and not an index I couldnt figure out how to implement.

Comment: The TreeSet is sorted, so if the size is 10, you know that subset(0,4) is the top 5 and subset(5,9) is the bottom 5 (or vice versa, i m not sure)

Comment: assylias may be my question isnt clear. The no of entries that would be inserted in to the collection is huge (~100,000) but at any given time I want it to retain only the top N or Bottom N. Others would be discarded.

Comment: My idea was to use a TreeSet and before adding check size, if size <= N then insert and do nothing. Else insert and then remove the middle element. Due to the naturing sorting the middle element is the one that needs to be discarded. However how do i remove the middle element? I may have to iterate; that seems to the the only inefficeint way.

Comment: You are right, it's not as simple as I thought. Using 2 collections is maybe not a bad idea after all...

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You want **Sorting and Uniqueness**, Use `TreeSet from java.util.Collection`. **Your data will be automatically sorted in the natural ordering and Uniqueness will be maintained**.

**2.** Use `Collections.reverse()` to **reverse the Collection** as you desire...

Comment: I do have a TreeSet and the elements are ordered based on my own compare implementation but this set needs to be bounded to n elements and not contain more than its necessary. Primarily to optimize on memory as the no of elements inserted would be high.

Comment: Handle it with a logic at the time the data is to be inserted.. like if (mtree.size()>n){ // It has reached the limits} else { mtree.add(value) }

Comment: By this I am able to implement "Top N" or "Bottom N" but doesnt work for "Top and Bottom N" scenario..

Comment: I am yet not getting a clear picture...can you please illustrate it.. then i could easily code it for you

Comment: Vivek, the way I imagine this using a TreeSet; Top N - discard from tail. Bottom N - Discard from head. Top and Bottom N - Discard from middle. Now the question is merely how to dicard from the middle of a Treeset. E.g. in a Top & Bottom 10 scenario when the 11th element is added the 6th element has to be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Because I love writing collections on a Sunday afternoon like that,

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TopBottom {

    public int[] top;
    public int[] bottom;

    public TopBottom(int size) {
        top = new int[size];
        Arrays.fill(top, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        bottom = new int[size];
        Arrays.fill(bottom, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public void add(int element) {
        int n = Arrays.binarySearch(top, element);
        if (n < -1) {
            System.arraycopy(top, 1, top, 0, -2 - n);
            top[-2 - n] = element;
        }
        int m = Arrays.binarySearch(bottom, element);
        if (m < 0 && bottom.length >= -m) {
            System.arraycopy(bottom, -1 - m, bottom, 0 - m, bottom.length + m);
            bottom[-1 - m] = element;
        }
    }

    public void add(int... elements) {
        for (int each: elements) {
            add(each);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.append('[');
        for (int each: bottom) {
            buf.append(each);
            buf.append(", ");
        }
        for (int each: top) {
            buf.append(each);
            buf.append(", ");
        }
        buf.setLength(buf.length() - 2);
        buf.append("]");
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public static class Examples {

        @Test
        public void shouldHoldOnlyTopFiveAndBottomFive() {
            TopBottom tp = new TopBottom(5);
            tp.add(5, 15, 10, 1, 12, 8, 11, 2, 16, 14, 9, 3, 20, 7);
            assertEquals("[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 12, 14, 15, 16, 20]", tp.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

It uses the `Arrays#binarySearch` method, which (besides finding existing elements) returns the insertion point into sorted list if an element is missing. Insertion points are returned as `(-1-index)` thus the check whether `n` respectively `m` are negative and later the expressions of the form `-1-n` to get the insertion point or the point before and after.

Comment: I solved this a little differently; cant tell which solution would be faster. My implementation; for each insert converted the TreeSet elements in to an array; then looked for the element at position (n/2) and removed it from the TreeSet. Essentially remove the middle element from the Treeset. The performance should be fine as we are dealing with limited(n) number of elements in the tree.